# Include sharing settings in an unlocked package?

Tags: salesforcedx, sharing, unlocked-package

Is it possible to include a sharing setting change in an unlocked package?  Essentially the change is to make an object Public Read/Write for External users, whereas now it is Private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, administrators need to use a separate deployment or manual change to specify the sharing setting. You *do*, however, need to specify the sharing model in your `<Object-Name>.object-meta.xml` file if you want to use related features. For example, AccountShare will only be available in your Unlocked Package if sharingModel is set to Read or Private.

Comment: Would you clarify what you mean by "separate deployment"?  A second package?

Comment: @MichaelSobczak No, just a normal deployment (e.g. package.xml). You can't change an organization's sharing model using Unlocked Packages, as far as I can tell.

Comment: you're talking about an Ant deployment, then?

Comment: @MichaelSobczak Ant, sfdx force:mdapi:deploy, force:source:deploy, etc, yes. Anything that can actually modify the sharing model of the object.

Comment: @sfdcfox How to handle the package version creation if we need OWD changed to public read in order to test the code in unit tests properly? It works in orgs, works in scratch orgs, not during package version creation.

Comment: @jm. You can specify unpackaged metadata to be pre-deployed for the version, see [this help topic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sfdx_packaging_path_unpackaged_md_ga.htm&type=5&release=230).